# uso de Type en searchNearbyWithRadius con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, apigoogle

actualmente hago una app con la API de google places, uso el paquete

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
```

Aqui pido los lugares y sus tipos

```
final response = await places.searchNearbyWithRadius(
          Location(lat: position.latitude, lng: position.longitude),
          1000,
          type: 'doctor',
        );
```

Como se pueden pasar más de un tipo a este parametro, se puede?
Intente con

```
type: 'doctor|hospital',
```

Pero sin exito. Gracias